# Beta decay mechanics?

Tags: electrostatics, nuclear-physics

Since a beta minus particle is being emitted from a positively charged nucleus. Does it not experience an attractive electrostatic force? And shouldnt this present the beta particle from leaving the nucleus?

Comment: Rocket ships also feel an attractive force of gravity from the Earth, but that doesn't seem to stop them

Comment: To expand on @SeñorO's point, compare the Rydberg energy (13.6 eV) to a beta KE of 500 keV or so.

Answer (score 2):

Beta decay particles are highly energetic. While (beta minus particles) may experience an attractive force, they have more than enough kinetic energy to avoid capture by the nucleus.

There is however a process called *electron capture* also mediated by the weak interaction, where a nucleus captures a *shell* electron, and decreases its proton number by one, with the emission of a neutrino. For this reason, this process is also sometimes referred to as *inverse beta decay*.